# Micromax Funbook tablet frozen at boot screen. No clockwork mod recovery - how to restore?

Tags: recovery-mode, root-access, micromax-funbook

I have a Micromax Funbook tablet (codename:P300) running Android 4.0.3.

While playing with a file explorer, I accidentally moved a file from /system folder. Yes, the device came as rooted and I had enabled root explorer and mounted the partition as writable. I  did so because I was mistakenly taken an assumption that I had installed Clockworkmod Recovery mod recovery.

Upon restart, the device does not go beyond bootloader image (it just says "Funbook" for ever).  I had attempted restart into recovery by pressing option button and then powering on.  To my nasty surprise, now only I realised that I had not installed Clockworkmod Recovery and landed on some recovery with following options:

Android system recovery <3e>

1. Reboot system now
2. Apply update from external storage
3. wipe data/factory reset
4. wipe cache partition
5. apply update from cache

Can anyone can help in restoring the tablet to original ROM? Even if I have ROM file, without Clockworkmod Recovery how can I recover?

Comment: Does ADB work, either in the stock recovery, or if you boot the system normally to the point where it hangs?

Comment: Thanks Chris, I did not have an opportunity to try what you said as by the time I read your words, I had flashed another ROM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [link](http://funbook.gizmolord.com/installing-clean-android-ics-on-micromax-funbook/) helped me to flash a rom image. As an additional benefit, this ROM seems to be faster than Micromax's original ROM and also claims to support a list of 3G dongles.  The previous (i.e. original) ROM I had did not support Reliance and BSNL's 3G dongles.

As in a settings menu the following dongles are supported (I haven't got any 3G dongle to test):

WCDMA:
Huawei(E230, E176G, E160E, 182G, E1782, E1750 UMG1691), ZTE (MF633BP-1, MF633, MF637U)

CDMA2000/EVDO:
Huawei(E150, EC1261, EC122, EC156, EC1270), ZTE (AC580, AC2736, AC2746)

After re flashing, I installed clockworkmod recovery as per [this](http://www.slatedroid.com/topic/30683-installing-clockwork-mod-recovery/) link as well.

Answer (score 0):

I just plugged it in, did a reboot with the on/off and volume switches like turning it off, and I came to life again!  Yay!