# Flash Custom Rom on china tablet

Tags: custom-roms, rom-flashing, clockworkmod-recovery

I have a chinese tablet with the allwinner a13 chip, that I want to flash a custom rom to. Rom Manager doesn't recognize the device, so I can't install clockworkmod recovery...

So how can I go about flashing a custom rom to this tablet?

same specs as seen here http://www.slatedroid.com/topic/51050-quantex-9-kb901/

Comment: Didn't they have any hints on that where you got the ROM from? Usually when they're posted, some README goes along.

Comment: Nope. The Rom manager message (I assume that's what we're talking about) just said that I had to wait till it was supported.

Answer (score 1):

Micromax Funbook is a clone of AllWinner A10 chipset based tablet. I once had to flash a ROM and asked this [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25575/micromax-funbook-tablet-frozen-at-boot-screen-no-clockwork-mod-recovery-how-t).

The link that I had used to flash the ROM including the ROM itself are available in the answer.  You could try that flash tool to install a ROM of your choice - but there is a pretty good chance for you to be in trouble if you flash an incompatible ROM.

Answer (score 1):

I recently bought a Trio Stealth Pro 7c, which uses the Allwinner a13 chip. In order to flash a rom, you must use [LiveSuit](http://www.topnotchtablets.com/LivesuiteInstall), which is a Chinese-made, Windows-only program. You boot your tablet into recovery mode, and LiveSuit will flash the rom you provide.

The rom must be in a specific format, so if you want to create a custom rom to distribute, you have to go through a lot of steps. For more details see [this forum](http://www.slatedroid.com/topic/45961-tutorial-how-to-fix-a-a10-livesuite-rom/) or [this post*](http://www.schrauger.org/content/how-to-upgrade-a-trio-stealth-7-model-7c-a13-from-ics-to-jb).

There are a number of pre-built roms for A10, but A13 roms are more difficult to find (if only for the fact that most people don't realize there is a difference).

You can install ClockWorkMod on your tablet, if you want, but you probably won't be using it to flash roms. I did, but I am still unable to simply flash a rom properly. You can still to full nandroid backup and restores.

*Full disclosure: I wrote this post. Actually, your question caused me to finish my rough draft and post the finalized version.

Comment: Thank you - Does this mean I can't backup the existing rom, or can I use nandroid (pre LiveSuit) to create a backup of the current rom, should I need to revert?

Comment: I think you can back up the existing rom using nandroid. The backup will only be restorable via the recovery tool (CWM). But note that when you flash a new rom via LiveSuit, it also wipes out your custom recovery. So after flashing the new rom, you must reinstall clockworkmod in order to restore the nandroid backup.

Answer (score -3):

Follow the 5 steps

1. Root Your Android phone

To Know how to root it just type [model] root in google & follow it

1. Install the free app Rom Manager  From clockworkmod in google play
2. Download the rom You want to try in sd card

4 Flash it

5 Reboot

Comment: That's a pretty generic guideline, no emphasis on specific device as per the OP's question - specifically *a chinese tablet with the allwinner a13 chip* and also, the OP mentioned *Rom Manager doesn't recognize the device, so I can't install clockworkmod recovery*